# Passing a class as function parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function doSomething($param, Class) {
Class::someFunction();
}

$someVar = doSomething($param, Class);
```

Is it possible?

To explain better what I'm trying to do. I have a helper function in Laravel to generate unique slugs, so I have to query different tables depending on where the slug is going to be saved.

Actual code I'm trying to write:

```
$newcat->slug = $helper->uniqueSlug($appname, Apk);

public function uniqueSlug($str, Apk)
    {
        $slug = Str::slug($str);

        $count = Apk::whereRaw("slug RLIKE '^{$slug}(-[0-9]+)?$'")->count();

        return $count ? "{$slug}-{$count}" : $slug;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: pass it as a string? `doSomething($param, 'PDO');` then `$class::somefunction()`?

Comment: I didn't really understand from your example. Could you please be a bit more clear?

Comment: You're attempting to dynamically invoke a static method, which is basically a design flaw. It's possible @Marc B's string suggestion, but better would be using an instance method and `function doSomething($param, MyBaseClass $instance) { $instance->someFunction(); }`

Comment: But how do I call the function in your example? Something like this?
`$instance = new MyBaseClass; doSomething($param, $instance)` ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the magic `::class` constant:

```
public function uniqueSlug($str, $model)
{
    $slug = Str::slug($str);

    $count = $model::whereRaw("slug RLIKE '^{$slug}(-[0-9]+)?$'")->count();

    return $count ? "{$slug}-{$count}" : $slug;
}

$newcat->slug = $helper->uniqueSlug($appname, Apk::class);
```

Answer (score 17):

In PHP, classes (or class names) are handled as strings. **Since PHP 5.5**, you can use `YourClass::class` to get a fully qualified class name.
If you want to get it in an earlier version of php, you can (if you have already an object of the calss) either do the following:

```
<?php
$obj = new YourClass();
// some code

$clazz = get_class($obj);
?>
```

or, you can implement a static method in your class, like this:

```
<?php

class YourClass {
    // some code

    public static function getClassName() {
        return get_called_class();
    }
?>
```

If you want to pass a class to a function, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
function do_somthing($arg1, $clazz) {
    $clazz::someStaticMethod($arg1);
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
function do_somthing($arg1, $clazz) {
    call_user_func(array($clazz, 'someStaticMethod')), $arg1);
}
?>
```

If you need to call a non-static method of that class, you need to instanciate it:

```
<?php
function do_somthing($arg1, $clazz) {
    $obj = new $clazz(); 
    $obj->someNonStaticMethod();
}
?>
```

**Note:** You can use PHP type hinting with passed class names:

```
<?php
function do_somthing($arg1, MyInterface $clazz) {
    $obj = new $clazz(); 
    $obj->someInterfaceMethod();
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah, did not know interfaces would work type hinting on names. Exactly what I actually needed to make sure the intent is not forgotten

Answer (score 4):

I think you can.

Send the class name as string parameter then use it like below.

```
$classtr = "yourparam";// param comes from the function call.

$obj = new $classtr;
$obj->method();
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the class name as string parameter you need use the namespace. For example:

```
function defineClass()
{
  $class = "App\MyClass"; // mention the namespace too
}

function reciveClass($class)
{
   $class:: // what do you need,
}
```