# Passing PHP class as parameter?

Tags: php

How can I pass the current class as a parameter?
Example:

```
class Example 
{
    public function test() {
        $class = new Class2(I want to pass the Example class instance here)
    }
}

class Class2 
{
    public function __construct(Example $example) {
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614696/passing-a-class-as-function-parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example 
{
    public function test() {
        $class = new Class2(new static());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it as $this, new self() or new static(). and you will get the same result.

```
class Example 
{
    public $name = "test";

    public function test() {
        return $class = new Class2($this);
    }
}

class Class2 
{
    private $example = null;
    public function __construct(Example $example) {
        $this->example = $example;
    }

    public function testMe() {
        echo $this->example->name;
    }

    public function setExampleName($name) {
        $this->example->name = $name;
    }
}

$e = new Example();

$e->test()->testMe();
```

the result:

```
test
```

Answer (score 0):

send $this in as the parameter during object creation. Because $this represent the current class object Which Example here

```
class Example { 
  public function test() {
   $class = new Class2($this);
  } 
 }
```