# PHP Notice: Object of class MyClass could not be converted to int

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop

#### `PHP Notice: Object of class MyCourse could not be converted to int in /home/usr/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 310`

**post-template.php** line 310:

```
    if ( $elements['page'] > count( $elements['pages'] ) ) { // if the requested page doesn't exist
        $elements['page'] = count( $elements['pages'] ); // give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist
    }
```

Class call within **register_shortcodes():**

```
if ( $has_course ) { // if a quiz is supposed to be rendered with the course
                $entity = new MyCourse( array( 'id' => $post->post_parent ) );
                $presenter = $entity->get_presenter();
            }
```

**Encountered this issue:** while troubleshooting H5P shortcodes within legacy codebase.

**Question**: Is count() the culprit throwing this error?

Comment: We don't know what your variables contains. But `$elements['page']` sounds like it could contain an object, while you're comparing it like if it was an integer (which would throw a notice like that)

Comment: @M.Eriksson You are correct. 

I believe this is where the MyCourse class is being compared as an integer within $elements[]

Currently looking through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614696/passing-a-class-as-function-parameter for possible solutions of returning a passable value to the count() function.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare? It makes no sense to check if an object is greater than the number of elements in an array.